# disable dragging in gridview qml

Tags: qt, gridview, qml

I would like to disable dragging in gridview using qml. This is what I have right now

```
GridView {
        id: appGridView
            anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: (appGridView.width / 2) ; cellHeight: 210
        focus: true
        model: proxyModel
        delegate: AppGridDelegate{}

        clip: true
    }
```

Please note that dragging property of flickable is read-only.

UPDATED:

I dont want the gridview to b moved when i press the mouse and drag the view up/down. the movement should be only when you flick the gridview. Basically why i want this is because when i select an item , i refresh the model to show the changes to the UI. Now, when the model is refreshed the current contentY position is changed and the view moves up.

Answer (score 4):

To dissable flickable behaviour you can set interactive to false.
[This property describes whether the user can interact with the Flickable. A user cannot drag or flick a Flickable that is not interactive.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#interactive-prop)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok thank but I dont think that it is relevant to Qt project:)

Comment: Yes.Only property `interactive` of `Flickable` which `GridView` inhrerits is not a read-only property, and `GridView` I am using can't drag and move.